Bonding question on new remote 400amp panel feeding 2 200amp panels
Just set up a remote 400 amp service panel with 2 200 amp disconnects.  Povider is going to dig up cureent 4/0 (2 hots and neutral) feeding orig panel on the house and hand it to me to terminate on one of the 200 disconnects. They will then drop 400amp service to meter.  I have installed another run about 50ft of 4/0 to my shop (2 hots a neutral and a ground as it appears the ground is now code)  so now i have basically 2 200 amp sub panels with thier own 200amp breakers.  From my understanding these 200 amp panels should not be bonded?  I did ground rod on the new 400amp location and the new 200 amp panel location and there is obviously rod at the old main panel. because i do not have a stand alone ground on the old feed that box stays bonded and the new box with the ground does not? please educate me, getting conflicting information.  The new ground wire i thin is confusing me.  If they both had 2 hots and a neutral i would not bond either panel and have the box grounded to the rod, with this dedicated ground going back to the 400amp meter i cant wrap my head around it.

Neutral and ground busses are only bonded together at the first panel.
All other panels must have the two busses separated.  The first panel and panels in detached buildings usually are required to have two ground rods, but depends on local regulations.
Newer code does require a ground wire back to the first panel.
Ground wire and ground rods serve two different functions.  Ground rods are more for providing a path for high(lighting) voltage.  The ground wire is more for your safety.

That is what i thought, yes i did use 2 rods at each local, i guess the new ground wire is what is confusing me, it lands on the bonded main panel so i would have to have it land on the neutral buss on the non bonded new panel?  It also appears i will have to unbond my exisitng panel and add a ground bus.

I guess my questions are then.. if my panels are now considered sub panels and are not to be bonded.  The new required green ground wire would land on a non bonded neutral bus corect? Seems redundant as the neutral from the meter does the exact same thing. And in the orig panel i need to unbond the neutral buss, add a ground buss and move all my ground wires to that buss leaving all neutrals unbound?

@Lamont  After the first panel  grounds and neutral are kept separate.  The ground wire only goes to the ground bus of other panels, not to the neutral bus.  The original/first panel you bond the ground and neutral busses together.  If you have a meter main panel, a meter box with a few breakers, then that is the first/main panel, and all others have separate neutrals and grounds.

Ok so the new run ground goes from bonded main panel buss to the ground buss in the new panel.  The old panel thst has no ground i must separate the grounds and neurals and unbind the neutral bar.

This new ground wire being bonded to neutral in main panel and landing on ground in new panel makes me think the new sub panel is now bonded.

@Lamont  The metal of the panel is bonded, but the neutral bus is insulated from the metal(or should be).  Some panel's neutral bus have a screw/strap to bond to ground, which must be removed(with power off) in panels used as sub panels.
